# Unhandled Promise rejection: caused by: Cannot read property 'touched' of null

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-forms

I'm trying to perform form validation in the below form but the validations are not happening. I'm getting an error

> "Unhandled Promise rejection: Error in
>   app/customers/customer.component.html:34:20 caused by: Cannot read
>   property 'touched' of null ;".

I'm using a FormBuilder and Built in Validators.
This is my component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Customer } from './customer';

@Component({
   selector: 'my-signup',
   templateUrl: './app/customers/customer.component.html'
})
export class CustomerComponent implements OnInit {
   customerForm: FormGroup;
   customer: Customer= new Customer();

   constructor(private fb: FormBuilder){}

   ngOnInit(): void {
      this.customerForm = this.fb.group({
          firstName: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)]],
          //lastName: {value:'', disabled:true},
          lastname: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(50)]],
          email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+')]],
          phone: '',
        notification: 'email',
        sendCatalog: true
    });
}


populateTestData(): void {
    this.customerForm.patchValue({
        firstName: 'Jack',
        lastName: 'Harkness',
        //email: 'jack@torchwood.com',
        sendCatalog: false
    });
}

save() {
    console.log(this.customerForm);
    console.log('Saved: ' + JSON.stringify(this.customerForm.value));
}

setNotification(notifyVia: string): void{
    const phoneControl = this.customerForm.get('phone');
    if (notifyVia === 'text'){
        phoneControl.setValidators(Validators.required);
    } else {
        phoneControl.clearValidators();
    }
    phoneControl.updateValueAndValidity();
}
}
```

This is my form.

```
<div class="panel panel-primary">
<div class="panel-heading">
    Sign Up!
</div>

<div class="panel-body">
    <form class="form-horizontal"
          novalidate
          (ngSubmit)="save()"
          [formGroup]="customerForm">
        <fieldset>
            <div class="form-group"
                [ngClass]="{'has-error': (customerForm.get('firstName').touched || customerForm.get('firstName').dirty) && !customerForm.get('firstName').valid }">
                <label class="col-md-2 control-label" 
                       for="firstNameId">First Name</label>

                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <input class="form-control" 
                           id="firstNameId" 
                           type="text" 
                           placeholder="First Name (required)" 
                           formControlName="firstName" />
                    <span class="help-block" *ngIf="(customerForm.get('firstName').touched || customerForm.get('firstName').dirty) && customerForm.get('firstName').errors">
                        <span *ngIf="customerForm.get('firstName').errors.required">
                            Please enter your first name.
                        </span>
                        <span *ngIf="customerForm.get('firstName').errors.minlength">
                            The first name must be longer than 3 characters.
                        </span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group"
                [ngClass]="{'has-error': (customerForm.get('lastName').touched || customerForm.get('lastName').dirty) && !customerForm.get('lastName').valid }">
                <label class="col-md-2 control-label" 
                    for="lastNameId">Last Name</label>

                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <input class="form-control" 
                           id="lastNameId" 
                           type="text" 
                           placeholder="Last Name (required)" 
                           formControlName="lastName"/>
                    <span class="help-block" *ngIf="(customerForm.get('lastName').touched || customerForm.get('lastName').dirty) && customerForm.get('lastName').errors">
                        <span *ngIf="customerForm.get('lastName').errors.required">
                            Please enter your last name.
                        </span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group"
                [ngClass]="{'has-error': (customerForm.get('email').touched || customerForm.get('email').dirty) && !customerForm.get('email').valid }">
                <label class="col-md-2 control-label" 
                    for="emailId">Email</label>

                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <input class="form-control" 
                           id="emailId" 
                           type="email" 
                           placeholder="Email (required)" 
                           formControlName="email"/>
                    <span class="help-block" *ngIf="(customerForm.get('email').touched || customerForm.get('email').dirty) && customerForm.get('email').errors">
                        <span *ngIf="customerForm.get('email').errors.required">
                            Please enter your email address.
                        </span>
                        <span *ngIf="customerForm.get('email').errors.pattern">
                            Please enter a valid email address.
                        </span>

                        <!-- This one does not work -->
                        <span *ngIf="customerForm.get('email').errors.email">
                            Please enter a valid email address.
                        </span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group"
                [ngClass]="{'has-error': !customerForm.get('phone').valid }">
                <label class="col-md-2 control-label" 
                for="phoneId">Phone</label>

                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <input class="form-control" 
                       id="phoneId" 
                       type="tel" 
                       placeholder="Phone" 
                       formControlName = "phone" />
                    <span class="help-block" *ngIf="customerForm.get('phone').errors">
                        <span *ngIf="customerForm.get('phone').errors.required">
                            Please enter your phone number.
                        </span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group" >
                <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Send Notifications</label>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <label class="radio-inline">
                        <input type="radio" 
                               value="email" 
                               formControlName = "notification">Email
                    </label>
                    <label class="radio-inline">
                        <input type="radio" 
                               value="text" 
                               formControlName = "notification">Text
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-8 checkbox" >
                    <label>
                        <input id="sendCatalogId"
                               type="checkbox"
                               formControlName="sendCatalog" >
                        Send me your catalog
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- <div *ngIf="customer.sendCatalog">
                <div class="form-group" >
                    <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Address Type</label>
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                            <label class="radio-inline">
                                <input type="radio" id="addressType1Id" value="home"
                                       [(ngModel)]="customer.addressType"
                                       name="addressType">Home
                            </label>
                            <label class="radio-inline">
                                <input type="radio" id="addressType1Id" value="work"
                                       [(ngModel)]="customer.addressType"
                                       name="addressType">Work
                            </label>
                            <label class="radio-inline">
                                <input type="radio" id="addressType1Id" value="other"
                                       [(ngModel)]="customer.addressType"
                                       name="addressType">Other
                            </label>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-2 control-label" 
                        for="street1Id">Street Address 1</label>
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <input type="text" 
                               class="form-control" 
                               id="street1Id" 
                               placeholder="Street address"
                               [(ngModel)]="customer.street1"
                               name="street1">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-2 control-label" 
                        for="street2Id">Street Address 2</label>
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <input type="text" 
                               class="form-control" 
                               id="street2Id"
                               placeholder="Street address (second line)"
                               [(ngModel)]="customer.street2"
                               name="street2">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-2 control-label" 
                        for="cityId">City, State, Zip Code</label>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <input type="text" 
                               class="form-control" 
                               id="cityId" 
                               placeholder="City"
                               [(ngModel)]="customer.city"
                               name="city">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <select class="form-control"
                                id="stateId"
                                [(ngModel)]="customer.state"
                                name="state">
                            <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Select a State...</option>
                            <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
                            <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
                            <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
                            <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
                            <option value="CA">California</option>
                            <option value="CO">Colorado</option>
                            <option value="WI">Wisconsin</option>
                            <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                    <input type="number"
                               class="form-control" 
                               id="zipId" 
                               placeholder="Zip Code"
                               [(ngModel)]="customer.zip"
                               name="zip">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>-->

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-2">
                    <span>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary"
                                type="submit"
                                [disabled]="!customerForm.valid">
                            Save
                        </button>
                    </span>
                    <span>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary"
                                type="button"
                                (click)="populateTestData()">
                            Test Data
                        </button>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
  </div>
 <br>Dirty: {{ customerForm.dirty }} 
 <br>Touched: {{ customerForm.touched }}
 <br>Valid: {{ customerForm.valid }}
 <br>Value: {{ customerForm.value | json }}
```

Could anyone help to identify the cause of this error ?

Comment: Did you try to uncomment lastName in your ngOnInit ?

Comment: @mickl - Yes i tried to uncomment the lastName without Validators and commented out the lastName with Validators. This worked and enabled all other validations but i need to put validation within the component for lastName as well, enabling that breaks the validation for all inputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using the save navigation operator to prevent the error:

```
customerForm.get('firstName')?.touched
```

---

Alternatively, as a different approach you can try using getters in your component to get the `formGroup` properties instead of calling the methods directly from your HTML, for example, in your `CustomerComponent` use:

```
get firstName() { return this.customerForm.get('firstName') };
get lastName() { return this.customerForm.get('lastName') };
// ... etc
```

and now in your HTML instead of using:

```
customerForm.get('firstName').touched
```

You can use

```
firstName.touched
```

---

PS: make sure your casing matches in your ts and your html, ie - `lastName` !== `lastname`